# Polymorphism with array

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I will try to quickly explain the problem.
I have a base class like this:

```
class ArrayEntry
{

}

class BaseClass
{
    ArrayEntry[] m_Array;
}
```

Those two are base classes.
So after this, I have those two classes:

```
class ClassA : BaseClass
{

}

class ClassAEntry : ArrayEntry
{

}
```

I would fill the m_Array with ClassAEntry but if I would like to call something like this:

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
for (ClassAEntry entry : classA.m_Array) 
...
```

I would get an error. So I would have to cast the entry each time I would like to access an array.

```
for (ArrayEntry entry : classA.m_Array)
{
ClassAEntry castedEntry = (ClassAEntry)entry;
..
}
```

I would not like to use a cast on 100 different methods just to be able to use a for each call.

Is there any more elegant solution to this ?

Comment: Remove `ArrayEntry[] m_Array;` from base class, add `ClassAEntry[] m_Array;` to `ClassA`.

Comment: This is classically known as the expression problem. More simply put: often people want to have all the benefits of polymorphism (pointer to base class in a collection) plus all the benefits of concrete types (knowing the actual type, so a specific operation can be performed).

A visitor approach can be useful if you only have to worry about a single type. Otherwise, if you're worried about two polymorphic types interacting and need to know their actual types, you should look into multimethods.

That said, if a pure virtual method on the base class makes sense... do that

Comment: All you really need is to deciare `BaseClass[] myPolymorphicArray`.  You'll automatically be able to call any methods in the base class; you'll still have to cast in order to call new/overridden methods on any subclass(es),

Comment: Thanks for reply @IgorTandetnik.
That's the source of the problem. I would have 10 different classes and all of them would have a array but with different type. To avoid code duplication, this would have to be in the base class. 
This would fix the problem if I only had one class.

Comment: `ArrayEntry[]` can't store `ClassAEntry`, the object will be sliced down to `ArrayEntry` when stored. Or did you mean to store pointers?

Comment: My Spidey•Sense is screaming "Liskov Substitution Principle" violation.

Comment: Then show an example that actually demonstrates the problem. In the question as currently stated, there is no duplicated code to avoid.

Comment: @Pajgla *To avoid code duplication* -- That is not a reason to choose dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: Belongs on code review overflow site, not here.

Comment: @Pajgla: it basically sounds like you want 1) a "collection" of objects (for example, an array), 2) each element sharing a set of "standard operations", 3) but the *implementation* of these "operations" can vary from object to object (depending on the object's subclass) .  Correct?  SUGGESTION: consider a [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)